What is the best way to set weights for weighted MSE in multi output regression?
I am working on a regression task where the goal is to predict 6 scalar output values from a given input. The input consists of decaying signal data, and the outputs are the parameters of the signal equation.
Initially, I thought this would be a straightforward task. My first approach was to train a simple MLP with 6 output nodes. However, I encountered an issue that the scales of the 6 parameters differ greatly.
To address this, I tried using a weighted MSE loss, where the weights were set as the inverse of the mean of each parameter in the labels. Unfortunately, this approach consistently performed worse than training 6 separate, (way) smaller networks for each parameter individually. When I used the standard MSE loss without weighting, the results were even worse.
I've also thought about normalizing the output labels based on the training dataset and use it on the inference. However, it is not generalizable (can't find better words sorry).
Is there any effective method I could try in this situation?

Likely enough, there is little we can recommend here. Any improvement will need to leverage your domain knowledge. If six separate simpler models perform best, then by all means, go with that!
